# Tomcat 6 - webapp migration

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

Im really new to Tomcat...
I recently moved a webapp from one server to another. I was just give a folder with the site files. I updated that db connections and dumped all the files into the root folder.

My problem is that now some of my links are not working. My links that worked before are formatted like this: http://mysite.com/info/s?s=1234

Now the link will only work if I remove the "info", like this http://mysite.com/s?s=1234

Obviously this is because I dumped all of the files into the root instead of setting it up inside the "info" folder.

My question is how do I setup tomcat to run in the "info" folder??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

info is basically was used as your root context in your previous web server. As you have dumped the files in the root webapps folder of your tomcat hence now the root context is "/". In order to have info in your URL, you need to create a directory "info" under tomcat/webapps directory and then dump the files of the same webapp to this directory. Restart your server and check the URLs

Comment: ive moved the files into the "info" folder but now I just get an 404 error as if there is nothing there. is there any configuration that I need to do to get it to work??

Comment: @JonDog check whether you have web.xml there. Also share the complete directory structure of your tomcat and and your webapp, so that people can help you better.

Comment: The directory structure is webapp/ROOT/info/  "info" contains all of the site files. There is a web.xml file inside webapp/ROOT/info/WEB-INF/

Comment: @JonDog Take info directory from ROOT and put it in webapp directory. Restart the server and test ur URLs

Comment: Its still the same 404 error. there isnt anything in the root folder at this point. how do i configure tomcat to run off a different folder.

Comment: now i get a 404 even when i move all of the files back into the root.

Comment: @JonDog can you share your server.xml from tomcat/conf folder

Comment: ive never changed anything in server.xml . it is the default setup.

Comment: @JonDog I understand you have not changed anything but it will be a good idea to compare the server.xml from both the servers. As we do the context configuraiton there, hence I am aksing for that

Comment: unfortunately I do not have the previous servers server.xml file.